# Rails create a view from active record

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.2

Can I create a postgresql view from the below code? Is it necessary?, because now it takes few second to load, but in the future I will have to add a date range on it. If yes, can someone help me to write it please.

```
    report = self.project_reports   
    results_total = report.where('value < ?', 50).group("key_id").select('key_id')
    fifty = report.where('value BETWEEN ? AND ?', 41, 50).group("key_id").select('key_id')
    forty = report.where('value BETWEEN ? AND ?', 31, 40).group("key_id").select('key_id')
    thirty = report.where('value BETWEEN ? AND ?', 21, 30).group("key_id").select('key_id')
    twenty = report.where('value BETWEEN ? AND ?', 11, 20).group("key_id").select('key_id')
    ten = report.where('value BETWEEN ? AND ?', 4, 10).group("key_id").select('key_id')
    three = report.where('value = ?', 3).group("key_id").select('key_id')
    two = report.where('value = ?', 2).group("key_id").select('key_id')
    one = report.where('value = ?', 1).group("key_id").select('key_id')
    pos = {fif: fifty.count.size, four: forty.count.size, thir: thirty.count.size, twen: twenty.count.size, te: ten.count.size, thr: three.count.size, tw: two.count.size, on: one.count.size, result_t: total}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be a real 'view' in the SQL sense (you can only create that via a DDL query), but you can certainly build an ActiveRelation (which is probably what you meant anyhow).  Note that you are switching between 'value' and 'position' arbitrarily, is that on purpose?  I'm using 'value' for consistency sake here:

```
group_sql = <<-SQL
  CASE WHEN value = 1 THEN 'one'
       WHEN value = 2 THEN 'two'
       WHEN value = 3 THEN 'three'
       WHEN value <= 10 THEN 'ten'
       WHEN value <= 20 THEN 'twenty'
       WHEN value <= 30 THEN 'thirty'
       WHEN value <= 40 THEN 'forty'
       WHEN value <= 50 THEN 'fifty'
SQL
report = self.project_reports.where('value < 50').group(group_sql)
positions = report.count
positions['total'] = positions.values.sum
```

Comment: http://alexpotrykus.com/blog/2013/04/10/postgres-views-in-rails/ is this not a view?

Comment: If you look through that article, you'll see that the actual view doesn't come in until the migration that begins with `create or replace view ...`.  That statement creates a view.  Running an arbitrary query can be used in a similar fashion as a view, but it trades off flexibility against performance.  You typically wouldn't start using a view until you were sure that the benefits in performance justify the difficulty in maintainability.  Either that, or if you enjoy difficult-to-maintain code :)  In this case, I don't see a reason yet for you to move to a real view (materialized or not).